# Me.Dirty moves currently selected record

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have an Access 2007 form that's giving me some headache.

I have a list of records that start as a combo box to pick a company and then a series of checkboxes to indicate the company's role.

[image: Screenshot]

If the user needs to add a new company, they'd pick the company name from the combo box, and then click the checkbox that indicates what role the company is playing. When the checkbox is checked, the form follows the following code to show a popup that captures additional information:

```
Private Sub chkOperationsAndMaintenance_AfterUpdate()
    'DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord'
    If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
    If chkOperationsAndMaintenance.Value = True Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "OmPopupForm", , , "CompanyProjectId = " & Me.CompanyProjectID, , acDialog
        Me.Requery
    End If
End Sub
```

This code will save the record on the CompanyProject table to create the row. It then pulls the CompanyProjectID (PK of the CompanyProject table) so it knows which ID to feed the popup.

The issue I'm having is that on the Me.Dirty line (and also the above commented-out acCmdSaveRecord), the entire form saves and refreshes, moving the selected row to the first record (in this case, "Gamesa") rather than the newly entered record. So the ensuing popup is fed the CompanyProjectID of the first record rather than the newly-entered record, and it also reads the "checked" state of the checkbox from the first record rather than the one upon which the user is working.

I doctored the code to look like this:

```
Private Sub chkOperationsAndMaintenance_AfterUpdate()
    Dim CPID As Long
    Dim CID As Long
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
    CID = Me.CompanyID
    'DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord'
    If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
    CPID = DLookup("MAX(CompanyProjectID)", "CompanyProject", "cpProjectID = " & Me.cpProjectID & _
        " AND CompanyID = " & CID)
    rs.Find "[CompanyProjectID] = " & CPID
    Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    If chkOperationsAndMaintenance.Value = True Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "OmPopupForm", , , "CompanyProjectId = " & Me.CompanyProjectID, , acDialog
        Me.Requery
    End If
End Sub
```

The idea with these alterations is that we'll get the FK from the parent form ("cpProjectID") and the CompanyID of the selection from the combobox, then save the record. Once the record is saved, we have the CompanyProjectID already stored, so then the rs.Find and Me.Bookmark lines will then select the record that matches that CompanyProjectID.

This sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't. Generally doesn't. In this case, I refreshed the parent form and the current form and attempted to add a new company and then click the "Owner" checkbox (which uses the same code as above, just a different checkbox ID) to see the Bookmark on the wrong row:

[image: Screenshot2]

At this point, I'm not sure what to do. If I don't save the record (via acCmdSaveRecord or Me.Dirty=False) then I don't have a CompanyProjectID to send as the input parameter for the ensuing popup, but if I do save the record, then the form changes the record and the wrong parameter is sent and the wrong checkbox's checked state is read. I can't just use an arbitrary index to work off of (such as acNewRec), as the user might need to edit an existing row instead of adding a new one.

I tried the method in this post already: [MS Access how to Update current row, move to next record, not first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731043/ms-access-how-to-update-current-row-move-to-next-record-not-first), but the find/bookmark isn't consistently working.

EDIT (12/15/2014)

I ended up going with the following VBA code:

```
Private Sub chkOperationsAndMaintenance_AfterUpdate()
    Dim CPID As Long
    Dim CID As Long
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
    CID = Me.CompanyID
    If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
    CPID = DLookup("MAX(CompanyProjectID)", "CompanyProject", "cpProjectID = " & Me.cpProjectID & _
        " AND CompanyID = " & CID)
    Do While Me.CompanyProjectID <> CPID
        If Me.CurrentRecord < Me.Recordset.RecordCount Then
            DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
        Else
            DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acFirst
        End If
    Loop
    If chkOperationsAndMaintenance.Value = True Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "OmPopupForm", , , "CompanyProjectId = " & Me.CompanyProjectID, , acDialog
        Me.Requery
    End If
End Sub
```

I feel like there has to be a better answer for this, but this is appearing to work right now. I have my end user/lab rat testing it at the moment, so I'll mark this complete if this pans out. I still think there has to be a better solution for this, but at the moment, this solution is able to capture the requisite ID to pass to the popup, and it selects the appropriate row after this ID is captured.

Comment: `Me.Requery` is the code that is shaking things up. It rebuilds the recordset from scratch, invalidates any bookmarks, and moves to the form to the first record.

Comment: This won't work in Rockie's case "the user might need to edit an existing row instead of adding a new one"

Comment: Exactly @Tom, thanks for both responding. The Requery isn't really interfering with the record selection, as the issues occur before the DoCmd.OpenForm and the requery is just to kind of finalize the user's changes on that record. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered saving the current position - like Me.CurrentRecord, then after the save reposition to the desired record. As an example, you could add a 'Before' or 'After' Insert to save the position, then later reposition. See the following:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim lCurRec As Long

Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
    lCurRec = Me.CurrentRecord
    Debug.Print "After Insert, Current: " & Me.CurrentRecord
End Sub

<<< YOUR SUB>>>
DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, Me.Name, acGoTo, lCurRec
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will work when adding a new record as well as when editing an existing record:

```
  Private Sub chkOperationsAndMaintenance_AfterUpdate()
  Dim c As Long
  Me.Dirty = False          
  If chkOperationsAndMaintenance Then
      DoCmd.OpenForm "OmPopupForm", , , "CompanyProjectId = " & Me.CompanyProjectID, , acDialog
      c = Me.CurrentRecord                 
      Me.Requery                           
      DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acGoTo, c       
  End If
  End Sub
```

I am guessing that your popup form does things that are specific to Operations & Maintenance, and does not change the values of any of the checkboxes on the main form. If this is the case, you don't need a Requery at all, and the code can be simplified:

```
  Private Sub chkOperationsAndMaintenance_AfterUpdate()
  Me.Dirty = False
  If chkOperationsAndMaintenance Then
      DoCmd.OpenForm "OmPopupForm", , , "CompanyProjectId = " & Me.CompanyProjectID, , acDialog
  End If
  End Sub
```

Comment: Lemme see if I can get that to work, slightly tweaked. The issue is that the Me.Dirty or the acCmdSaveRecord refreshes the form and selects the first entry in that form, so if I'm trying to work on the third entry, when it saves the record, it highlights the first and sends the ID from the first to the form. I need that record number saved BEFORE the form saves and highlights the first record. Thank you though!